# Plasma Dispersion relation simplification

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematics

I am trying to solve the following equation D(w,k) = $1-\frac{w_{p,e}^2}{2}[\frac{1}{(w-kv_0)^2}+\frac{1}{(w+kv_0)^2}]=0$  by rearranging it as $w^2 = D(k)$ (that is, write the it as $w^2$ = ... , such that $w$ does not appear on the right side). $w_{p,e}$ is a constant.

After some algebra, I stopped at here :
$\frac{2(w+k^2v_0^2)}{(w^2-k^2v_0^2)^2}=\frac{2}{w_{p,e}^2}$

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: There is a mistake in your last equation. It should be $\omega^2$ rather than $\omega$. In this way, you will get a second order equation with $\omega^2$ unknown.

Comment: For dimensional reasons, it is $\frac{\omega^2+k^2v_0^2}{(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2}=\frac{2}{\omega_{p,e}^2}$. This means that also your first equation contains a mistake.

Comment: you are right, there was a typo in the first equation it should be (w(p,e))^2 over 2 instead of the reciprocal. I updated it.

Comment: There is also a problem with your algebra. Please, check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us start from the equation
$$
\frac{\omega^2+k^2v_0^2}{(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2}=\frac{1}{\omega_{p,e}^2}.
$$
Choosing the unknown $x=\omega^2-k^2v_0^2$, you have to solve
$$
\frac{x+2k^2v_0^2}{x^2}=\frac{1}{\omega_{p,e}^2}.
$$
I think you can go on from here.

Comment: Substituting with x made it easier. Thank you